# Which jquery-rails gem version is working with Rails 3.0?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

According to the docs, the [jquery-ujs Installation](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation) is as easy as adding

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1'
```

to the Gemfile, and running:

```
$ bundle install
```

---

My app is running **Rails 3.0.15**, and `jquery-rails` seems to be compatible with it:

> For Rails 3.0 , run [...]

but when bundling `jquery-rails` 2.1, I seem to need Rails 3.1+:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails (~> 2.1) x86-mingw32 depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.1.0) x86-mingw32

    rails (= 3.0.15) ruby depends on
      railties (3.0.15)
```

What `jquery-rails` gem version is compatible with Rails 3.0?

*(also asked [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/286))*

Comment: Try this one : gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

Comment: Weird, the dependency for 2.0.2 is even higher: `jquery-rails (= 2.0.2) ruby depends on railties (< 5.0, >= 3.2.0) ruby`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying an earlier version of the gem

```
`gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'`
```

the dependency is even higher:

```
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails (= 2.0.2) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.2.0) ruby
```

So for Rails **3.0.15** I ended up taking out the version from the Gemfile altogether and ended up with version **1.0.19**.

```
Installing jquery-rails (1.0.19)
```